# Snails and Sums

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, summation

At the beginning of a $10\,\mathrm m$ long rubber band sits a snail.
Every day it crawls one meter ahead. Every night, when the snail is resting, an evil man stretches the tape evenly by $10\,\mathrm m$ out. (In the morning of the second
Day the band is $20\,\mathrm m$ long and the snail has made $2\,\mathrm m$.) Will the snail ever reach the end of the tape?

**My attempt:**

If this continues forever, we have $d_{\text{Snail}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{1}$ and $d_{\text{Tape}}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{10}$. They  are both equal to $\infty$ since $a\cdot \infty = \infty$. But how does that prove it?

Comment: Nice username :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of measuring the snail's (or snake's?) progress in meters, measure it in fractions of the entire rubber band, since that is a measure that stays the same during the nightly stretching.

Then on day $n$ it makes a progress of $1/10n$ rubber bands. So you want find out whether there's a $k$ such that
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac1{10n} \ge 1 $$
and we know this to be the case since the harmonic series diverges.

---

**A more vivid argument:** Start by painting 20 dots on the rubber band at equal intervals. The rubber *between* two dots stretches by 50 cm every night, but since the snail crawls at 100 cm a day, each morning it will be at least 50 cm closer to the *next* dot than it was the previous morning (unless it passed a dot yesterday). So it *will* inevitably reach the next dot. And all it needs to do to get all the way is to "reach the next dot" 20 times in a row.

*(Any fencepost errors in this argument are left for the reader to think around.)*

Comment: That's clever, thank you Makholm!

Comment: Since $\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac1{10n} \ge 1 \Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{1}{n}}\geq 10$ and by the proof Nicole Oresme the harmonic series diverges, thus the snail will reach it?

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: Yes -- after $12367$ days, or almost 34 years...

Comment: This is pretty counter-intuitive, isn't it? Yeah about  12366.468 days

Comment: @ParabolicAlcoholic: I've added another argument that may feel more intuitive.

Comment: it does, thank you.